# grogner que / dire que

Tags: constructions

Bonjour,

D'après Antidote, **grogner** :

> dire (quelque chose) d’une voix sourde, en grommelant. *Grogner des reproches*.

Donc, logiquement, il est possible de dire :

> Elle grogne qu'elle est mécontente. (1)

comme on dit :

> Elle dit qu'elle est mécontente. (2)

Pourtant, je ne trouve pas beaucoup d'exemples avec *grogner que* sur Google. Pourriez-vous me dire si la phrase (1) est correcte ?

Merci

Answer (score 3):

Cette phrase est correcte, on peut remplacer "dire" par une multitude de verbes pour préciser la façon de dire : "chuchoter", "crier", "hurler", etc.
De mémoire, je dirais que "grommeler que" est plus utilisé que "grogner que", mais ce dernier reste valide, même si le sens diffère légèrement.

Answer (score 3):

*Grogner* suggère plus des sons sourds et inarticulés qu'un discours intelligible. Ceci explique probablement la rareté des occurrences de *grogner que*.

On pourrait plutôt écrire:

> Elle grogne pour manifester son mécontentement.

Comment: Aussi c'est peut-être plus fortement associé à [certains emplois](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/cooc-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=grogner&cur=1&nmbr=6&lettr=indx_catlog_d&page=9QiYtIQYjzMA.html#zz9QiYtIQYjzMA).

Comment: Je pense qu'il est préférable d'écrire "cela" au lieu de "ceci" dans la deuxième phrase. [ceci et cela](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1634) _en somme, ce mot annonce que quelque chose va suivre, va être dit ou écrit._

Comment: @Oreste Je préfère garder *ceci* qui peut aussi faire référence à la dernière chose énoncée (*Grogner suggère...*), alors que *cela* ferait référence à la première qui se trouve dans la question: *je ne trouve pas beaucoup d'occurrences...* En gros, ce que j'ai écrit, c'est *Ceci explique cela*. La plupart des occurrences de *ceci dit* font de toute façon référence à quelque chose qui vient d'être dit donc cette règle est fragile. Il arrive même à Grevisse de ne pas la respecter... Cela dit, j'aurais pu bien sûr aussi écrire *Cela explique probablement* ou mieux *Ça explique probablement...*